# Redirect anything to a single php file with url rewriting

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect anything to my index.php file to do myself the redirection.

If i use this:

```
#RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

but that's not working because it is "looping" on the rule.

This works :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

but i want to redirect it even if it is an existing file or directory (i thing i will make specials routes for image, js and so on to redirect on them with php without loading any script.

In fact, if there were a "no-loop" flag, that would be fine.

Anybody knows the solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to avoid looping:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php)(.+)$ index.php?path=$1%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Uses [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (`?!`) to see if the string includes *index.php*. If it doesn't, then carry on with the rewrite!

Comment: Does it change the actual url in the browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the two Cond patterns with a check to see if you're hitting index.php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

that will redirect everything, EXCEPT the hits on index.php (to prevent loops).